# preg_match not working with text file in php

Tags: php, text, preg-match, str-replace

Looping through a text file in php, I'm using preg_match to detect if the line contains "default" and put a comma after that word instead of a space, but it's not working:

```
   $FSCS = "";

 //Read the txt file
if(($handle = fopen("FSCS.txt", "r")) != false)
{
//Loop through each line
  while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) != false)
  {
    if(preg_match("/default/", $data[0])) $FSCS .= str_replace("default ", "default,", trim($data[0]))."\n";        

    else $FSCS .= trim($data[0]).",";
  }
}
```

Every line is processed by the "else" statement

Comment: default needs to exist in the first cell of the line, not rest of the line.

Comment: It does, every second new line in the text file contains the word default. If I echo out $FSCS at the end, every line is there separated by commas. But default still has a space and not a comma after it.

Comment: @user2622416 The reason for that is because you're trimming the contents of `$data[0]` before `str_replace` searches for "default ", so the `trim` function removes the trailing space from "default " and then `str_replace` can't match "default " any more

Comment: Try to provide us some sample input data and expected result. You can try something like this: http://pastebin.com/CwJdMBbB

Answer (score 0):

```
$FSCS = "";

//Read the txt file
if (($handle = fopen("FSCS.txt", "r")) != false)
{
    //Loop through each line
    // Use fgets to read the whole line and use fgetcsv to read and parse a CSV file
    while(($data = fgets($handle, 1000)) != false)
    {
        // The \s matches whitespace
        if (preg_match("/default\s/", $data))
        {
            $FSCS .= preg_replace("/default\s/", "default,", $data) . "\n";        
        }
        else
        {
            $FSCS .= $data . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately doesn't work, says "Warning: fgets() expects at most 2 parameters, 3". If I remove ,"," from fgets, every second line is now in Chinese"

Comment: @user2622416 I've updated my answer to remove the "," and also to match the space after "default" better. Is every other line in Chinese in the original file? Have you specified 1000 as the line length on purpose?

Comment: The second line (with default in it), is still coming out as Chinese

Comment: An example of second line is "Declared in default 26th July 2011". I've removed 1000, still same

Comment: Chinese problem fixed, there was no DOCTYPE on page I was echoing output to.

Comment: Still not putting comma after "default" though

Comment: It's always going to the "else" section, preg_match("/default\s/", $data) is never true, but it should be as there are 1000s of lines that contain "default "